# redirect to route protected with middleware laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes, middleware

I have dashboard protected with guest middleware and I want to display a dashboard for every employer with the ID but I don't know how to get the ID in guest middleware I tried some solutions from stackoverflow but the ID returned is null

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null,$id)
{

    $employer=Employer::find($id);
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check())
        return redirect('/home');
      if(Auth::guard('job_seeker')->check())
      return redirect('job_seeker/profile');

      if(Auth::guard('employer')->check())
      return redirect('employer/dashboard',$employer);

    return $next($request);
}

    //web.php
    Route::get('/dashboard/{id}','Employer\Dashboard_Controller@show_dashboard')->name('employer/dashboard');


class Dashboard_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){

        $this->middleware('auth:employer');

    }

    public function show_dashboard($id){
        // $locations=Location::all();
        // $categories=Category::all();
        $employer=Employer::find($id);
        return view('employer.dashboard',compact('employer'));
    }

}
```

Comment: did u debug `$id` in your middleware?

Comment: yes it returns error Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::handle(), 3 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\job_board_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php on line 171 and exactly 4 expected